# How to show that $\int [Y(x)\frac{dZ(x)}{dx} + Z(x)\frac{dY(x)}{dx}]\, dx = Y(x)Z(x) + C$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

How can I show that 
$$\int\left[Y(x)\frac{dZ(x)}{dx} + Z(x)\frac{dY(x)}{dx}\right]\, dx = Y(x)Z(x) + C$$ 
when it is known that 
$$\frac{d}{dt}[f(x)] = \frac{df}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt} \tag{1.}$$
and 
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx} = \left[\frac{dx(f)}{df}\right]^{-1} \tag{2.}$$ 
I have (of course) divided the two expressions like below to individually solve for the two integrals, but I can't continue from that (supposing that my first step is correct)
$$\int\left[Y(x)\frac{dZ(x)}{dx}\right]dx + \int\left[Z(x)\frac{dY(x)}{dx}\right] \, dx$$
This problem is the problem number 12. from the first [Project PHYSNET](http://www.physnet.com) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \, ( f(x) \, g(x) ) = f(x) \, \frac{dg(x)}{dx} + \frac{df(x)}{dx} \, g(x)$$
then 
$$\int \left[ f(x) \, \frac{dg(x)}{dx} + \frac{df(x)}{dx} \, g(x) \right] \, dx = \int \left[ \frac{d}{dx} \, ( f(x) \, g(x) ) \right] \, dx = f(x) \, g(x) + c_{0}$$

Comment: You can prove the product rule by taking the logarithm of the chain rule, if you intend to use this to answer the question.

Comment: The chain rule being the first rule mentioned in my question and the one used in the answer by Leucippus, right? I don't really know how to take the logarithm of the chain rule and I have never heard about proving the product rule that way.